# Form inside $mdDiolog with angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How to use form inside `$mdDialog`  popup with submit functionality. Currently I am using it but still facing problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! Show the code you have tried so far, so you can get more specific advice. Learn more on how stackoverflow works by taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

you can use $mdDialogActions in $mdDialog popup for submit functionality...

```
<md-dialog-actions layout="row" class="pam">
    <button type="submit" class="lg-controller-btn md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</md-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: thanks .i have found a diffrent way and its working now .